# DB Raw query error in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

This is my sql.. When i run it to **phpmyadmin** it is run ok. But when i am going to run as **DB:raw in laravel5.5** it shows error. Here, **Auckland** is not column name.

> $result = DB::select("select DISTINCT(SELECT count(id) FROM
>   commercial_lease where LENGTH(CONCAT(region,city,"Auckland"))  =
>   LENGTH(location) ) as  listing_without_address ,(SELECT count(id) FROM
>   commercial_lease where LENGTH(CONCAT(region,city,"Auckland"))  <
>   LENGTH(location)) as listing_with_address ,(SELECT count(id)  FROM
>   commercial_lease WHERE first_agent_name = 'None' and
>   second_agent_name='None') as private_listing from commercial_lease");

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing quotes. Query is covered by double quotes and for `Auckland` you are trying to put these in double quotes again which is issuing an error.

To fix this issue you can escape your string like `\"Auckland\"` or using single quotes `'Auckland'`

```
$result = DB::select("select DISTINCT
(SELECT count(id) FROM commercial_lease where LENGTH(CONCAT(region,city,'Auckland')) = LENGTH(location) ) as listing_without_address ,
(SELECT count(id) FROM commercial_lease where LENGTH(CONCAT(region,city,\"Auckland\")) < LENGTH(location)) as listing_with_address ,
(SELECT count(id) FROM commercial_lease WHERE first_agent_name = 'None' and second_agent_name='None') as private_listing from commercial_lease");
```